# Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.lang.NullPointerException when starting Java application

Tags: java

I am starting a Java application with the following command line arguments:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12312 \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=12313 \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
     Main
```

My program exits immediately and I get the following error:

> Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.lang.NullPointerException

I am using Java 8 update 45 on Windows 7:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This error occurs if `com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port` is set to a port that is already in use. Try setting the property to a free port or killing the process that is currently using the port in question.

There is a reported bug [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048050) in Open JDK to improve this error message. It is fixed in Java 8 update 60 and Java 7 update 80.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue.
After killing older process using same JMX port, issue got resolved and tomcat started properly.