# Spark JobServer NullPointerException

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I'm trying to start a spark jobserver, here are the steps I'm following:

- I configure the local.sh based on the template.
- Then I run ./bin/server_deploy.sh and it finishes without any error.
- Configure local.conf.
- Run ./bin/server_start.sh in the deploy server.

But when I do the last step I get the following error:

> Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.lang.NullPointerException

Note: I'm using spark 1.4.1. I'm using version 0.5.2 from jobserver (https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/tree/v0.5.2)

Any idea in how I can fix this (or at least debug it).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The error log does not provide much information.

I encountered the same error. For my case, I had another instance of the JobServer running (and somehow ./bin/server_stop.sh did not catch it). It works after I manually killed the other process.

Hint : [Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.lang.NullPointerException when starting Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908492/error-exception-thrown-by-the-agent-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-start)